# How to use messagebox instead of wcout

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How can I show the file name and some string in a messagebox?

I use this code:

```
wcout<<L"The File Path: [ "<<filename<<" ] Is Wrong";
```

but now I want to use a messagebox instead of `wcout`.

```
MessageBoxW(NULL,L"The File Path: [ "+filename+L" ] Is Wrong" , (LPCWSTR)L"File Content", MB_OK);
```

Comment: Ok, C != C++. Drop the C tag and probably should add `winapi`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , have u tried this - show us what you did

Comment: I'm beginner, how can I do this?

Comment: @user3105142 - Please, *never* cast pointers to strings like you're doing now.  Doing stuff like this `(LPCWSTR)` is a red flag that you are doing something terribly wrong.  If you wind up doing that to get past a compiler error, go back, remove the cast, and fix the problem.  Use the correct string type so that casting is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::wostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to format the text for your messagebox:

```
std::wostringstream msg;
msg << L"The File Path: [" << filename << L"] Is Wrong";
```

And pass `msg.str().c_str()` to the messagebox

```
MessageBox(NULL,msg.str().c_str(),L"File open error",MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
```

Comment: **it has this error:**  no operator "<<" matches these operands    operand types are: std::wostringstream << const wchar_t

Comment: @user3105142 There was a typo (missing `L` before the 2nd string literal). You should have got the same error using `std::wcout`, the interfaces are actually the same. You may try again (I didn't compile this sample).

Comment: **I try this:**  `msg<<L"The File Path: [ "<<filename<<L" ] Is Wrong";`  **but still has error**

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I've been copying and adapting this sample from MSDN's reference page. Removed casts now.

Comment: That famous `std::std::wostringstream`.

Comment: @user3105142 I've done a minimal compilable sample here now: http://ideone.com/UuThli Sorry there was another typo, you need `msg.str().c_str()`.

Comment: Alternatively, `MessageBoxA` will work quite ewll in English without the `L""` wide strings.

Comment: @MSalters _"ewll"_ is a nice ambiguation of _"evil"_ and _"well"_ actually (never mind :-) ).

Comment: The correct API to use with Unicode strings is `MessageBoxW`.